# Code generation for .Net MVC 4.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I really hope that this isn't a duplicate post somewhere else on SO but I've searched long and hard and I'm coming up blank.

In PHP if you used a framework like CakePHP you could "bake" your project which would generate the code for your models, views and controllers using your MySQL database ERD (see here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html). This saves tons of time and has become a requirement for me these days.

That said. I can't seem to find any information if a similar function exists either in Visual Studio 2012 or the MVC 4.5 framework. Does anyone know if I can "bake" a .Net MVC 4.5 project from my DB schema?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: search for t4 asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Scaffolding. You can read a nice tutorial on codeproject: [Database First Development with ASP.NET MVC Scaffolding and Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482801/DatabaseplusFirstplusDevelopmentpluswithplusASP-NE)

Comment: Thanks and @Daniel I appreciate you guys taking the time to respond!